# BeanFactory Can not Be Resolved To a Type

Tags: java, spring

```
BeanFactory factory=new xmlBeanFactory (new ClassPathResource ("com/pi/common/application- context.xml"));
```

while i am giving this code in my class It is Giving Error That
 `BeanFactory Can not Be Resolved To a Type` i am using Spring 3.05 and same for classPathResource

Comment: Have you added spring.jar in classpath..which Ide ur using

Comment: Yes I have added jar file

Comment: Still are you getting same error after adding spring.jar ?

Comment: Which IDE ur using ? that problem occurs when jars are not in the classpath

Comment: Yes I have already added and build jar files

Comment: @naren I am using spring tool suit

Comment: check this same prob as yours ..http://www.coderanch.com/t/61011/oa/spring-eclipse

Comment: try with other beanFactory types ..like applicationContextbeanfacoty

Comment: check `BeanFactory` is in `CLASSPATH` or not by `ctrl+shift+t` type classname

Answer (score 0):

First of all delete all jar file and go to your project folder and make a new folder like libs after that past all spring core jar file.

after that run your first spring program.